# Vertically centering inside a div with vh

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, centering, viewport-units

I'm currently trying to center an image inside a div that has it's dimensions set with vh. I tried using the `display:table-cell;` method which centered the image but began messing with the vw of other elements. I was wondering if there was another simpler way to be vertically centering this image inside a div that as vh. I know this might be a little confusing so hopefully my code down below can help!

Html:

```
<div class="graphic" style="background-color:#ff837b">
    <img src="images/WAInduo-02.svg" style="width: 100%; height: 50%;" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#induoIntro .graphic {
    display:block;
    height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: @Sid unfortunately I can't sue that method as you need a specified height which I can't do to using vh

Comment: Create a jsfiddle. Give us exactly what you have tried so far. And when you saying messing with your other elements, what are those other elements, with the same class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that `vertical-align:middle` has some inconsistency with `vw` unit. Try positioning approach.
Here is the solution for you.

CSS code:

```
.graphic {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.graphic img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wdnQL/)

Comment: While this does center the image correctly, it makes the content below it disappear. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Can you update the fiddle with your code, I can help you resolve it

Comment: Nvm I figured it out!Just had to remove position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width: 100%; from .grpahic. Thanks! Can you explain how this work's a little though?

Comment: Its combination of positioning img and applying margin:auto, is doing trick in this case.